# how to work with Derived Tables

Tags: sql

I am trying to understand a derived tables I kinda have an idea but still messing with it. I did this code that I dont think is right. I don't know if I have something input wrong or left something out. The table I am working with is a distinct company name from the customers table where the orders have a higher discount than.2.I have been looking over it maybe I have some of the names backwards or something.

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.CompanyName
From Customers As c
Join
(Select OrderID
From Orders as o
Join [Order Details] as od
ON c.Customers = od.OrderID
Where od.OrderID = '<.2'
```

The last Part is not working so well with the.2

How the columns are set up in the northwind database you click on tables and go down to see the dbo.Order Details and click on columns you will find OrderId, ProductID, UnitPrice, Quantity, Disounts. Then you will have the Custumers table which had CustomerID, CompanyName, ContactName, ContactTitle, Address, City, Region, PostalCode, COuntry, Phone, and Fax. Now if you go under the order table you will have OrderID, CustomerID, EmployeeID, OrderDate, RequiredDate, ShippedDate,ShipVia, Frieght, ShipName, ShipAddress, ShipCity, ShipRegion, ShipPostalCode, ShipCountry.

Comment: I doubt the discount value is stored in the `od.OrderID` column. Is there another column for that value?

Comment: Yes in the Order details

Comment: sql dialects and features vary significantly from one vendor to another.  You should update your question to indicate which one you are working with.

Comment: @st1984: And that column name would be...?

Comment: See if you go down to dbo.Order Detail and look under it you will see the discount

Comment: @st1984 LOL. I don't have access to your system, so I can't look under the OrderDetail table to find the discount. You've got to give us the details on your tables and column names if you want help writing a query.

Comment: In sql server, at least, a derived table needs both a closing parenthesis and an alias. However the selected answer is better for this particualr query anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do it.

```
SELECT c.CompanyName
    FROM Customers c
    WHERE EXISTS(SELECT NULL
                     FROM Orders o
                         INNER JOIN [Order Details] od
                             ON o.OrderID = od.OrderID
                                 AND od.Discount > .2
                     WHERE o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID)
```